# Jquery plugin with prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying on the basics of Jquery plugin and the prototype concept, but ended up in an unusual behavior.

HTML :

```
<div>
    <span>
        <textarea>Text Area with 500 characters. Adding Some text.</textarea>
        <span class="cl"></span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <textarea>Text Area with 100 characters</textarea>
        <span class="cl"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
(function ($) {
    var tisCharsLeftCntxt = null;

    function fnCharsLeft(ele, genStngs) {
        this.jqe = $(ele);
        this.maxChars = genStngs.maxChars;
        tisCharsLeftCntxt = this;
        this.fnInit();
    }
    fnCharsLeft.prototype = {
        fnInit: function () {
           tisCharsLeftCntxt.fnUpdateRemainingChars();
            tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.keyup(function (event) {
                key = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
                if ((37 != key) && (38 != key) && (39 != key) && (40 != key)) {
                    tisCharsLeftCntxt.fnUpdateRemainingChars();
                }
            });
        },
        fnUpdateRemainingChars: function () {
            var charsLft = tisCharsLeftCntxt.maxChars - tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.val().length,
                jqeDestToUpdt = tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.siblings('.cl');
            charsLft = (charsLft < 0) ? 0 : charsLft;
            if (charsLft) {
                jqeDestToUpdt.text(charsLft + ' more of ' + tisCharsLeftCntxt.maxChars + ' characters');
            } else {
                tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.val(tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.val()
                    .substring(0, tisCharsLeftCntxt.maxChars));
                tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe.scrollTop(tisCharsLeftCntxt.jqe[0].scrollHeight);
                jqeDestToUpdt.text("Maximum limit of " + tisCharsLeftCntxt.maxChars + " characters reached");
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn = function (genStngs) {
        return $(this).data("charsleft", new fnCharsLeft(this, genStngs));
    };
})(window.jQuery);
$('div span:nth-child(1) textarea').fnCharsLeftPlgn({maxChars: 500});
$('div span:nth-child(2) textarea').fnCharsLeftPlgn({maxChars: 100});
```

Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/5UQ4D/ & http://jsfiddle.net/5UQ4D/1/

Requirement is, the plugin should show the number of characters that can be added in a text-area. If there is only one text-area in a page this is working good. But if there are more than one, only the text-area which is last associated with the plugin is working properly.

With respect to code here, In both the text-area number of characters left is updated correctly during initialization (only for the first time). But later when the text area content is changed, only the second with 100 chars (or the most recent text-area associated with the plugin) is working properly.

Seems like, I'm failing to restrict the plugin context independently to a text-area. Please Advice,..

Comment: `$.jQuery.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn` should be `$.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn` (`$` being the param which you're passing as `window.jQuery`)

Comment: Sorry, it was a copying error. Check out the JS fiddle, the code is proper over there, as you have mentioned. Updated the code here too,.

Comment: You have global var tisCharsLeftCntxt = null; through which you accessing your elements inside your methods...that's why only last one  textarea is active

Comment: @NikitaHolovach : Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

As mentioned in the comments, you're creating a variable named `tisCharsLeftCntxt` outside of the other contexts, then assigning `this` to it in your constructor. Every time you run your plugin you stomp on `tisCharsLeftCntxt` with a new `this`.

There is no reason to use a reference to `this` in the wholesale fashion in which you have. There is only one place in your code where the scope changes such that `this` is no longer your instance. That place is inside of the `keyup` event handling function. You should localize your aliasing of `this` to just the method which contains that event handler.

**Problem 2:**

I believe another part of your problem (this would be seen if you ran the plugin against a selector which matched more than one element) is inside of the plugin function (the one which lives off of `$.fn`).

```
$.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn = function (genStngs) {
    return $(this).data("charsleft", new fnCharsLeft(this, genStngs));
};
```

It should be:

```
$.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn = function (genStngs) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).data("charsleft", new fnCharsLeft(this, genStngs));
    });
};
```

When directly inside of a method which has been added to the jQuery prototype (`$.fn`), `this` refers to the entirety of the current collection, not an element. A plugin should `each` itself in order to run element specific logic against its individual members.

Without using `.each()` you are calling `.data()` against an entire collection, setting all of their `charsleft` data properties to the one instance of `fnCharsLeft`. By using `.each()` you create a new instance of `fnCharsLeft` for each of the elements in the collection.

Since the `.each()` then returns the collection, and a plugin should be chainable, you simply return it.

A rule of thumb is that if you're passing `this` into the jQuery factory (`$()`) directly inside of a plugin, function then you're doing something wrong since it is already the collection. As a second rule of thumb, almost all plugin definitions except those which are intended to return info about an element (such as `.val()`, `.html()`, or `.text()` when not given a param) should start with `return this.each(function() {...`

**Solutions:**

Bringing those changes together results in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5UQ4D/4/

And this code:

```
(function ($) {
    var fnCharsLeft = function (ele, genStngs) {
        this.jqe = $(ele);
        this.maxChars = genStngs.maxChars;
        this.fnInit();
    };
    fnCharsLeft.prototype = {
        fnInit: function () {
            var instance = this;

            this.fnUpdateRemainingChars();
            this.jqe.on('keyup', function (e) {
                key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

                if (37 != key && 38 != key && 39 != key && 40 != key) {
                    instance.fnUpdateRemainingChars();
                }
            });
        },
        fnUpdateRemainingChars: function () {
            var charsLft = this.maxChars - this.jqe.val().length,
                jqeDestToUpdt = this.jqe.siblings('.cl');

            charsLft = charsLft < 0 ? 0 : charsLft;

            if (charsLft) {
                jqeDestToUpdt.text(charsLft + ' more of ' + this.maxChars + ' characters');
            } else {
                this.jqe
                    .val(this.jqe.val().substring(0, this.maxChars))
                    .scrollTop(this.jqe[0].scrollHeight);

                jqeDestToUpdt.text("Maximum limit of " + this.maxChars + " characters reached");

                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.fnCharsLeftPlgn = function (genStngs) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).data('charsleft', new fnCharsLeft(this, genStngs));
        });
    };
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for both solution and information. Had a strange feeling on "tisCharsLeftCntxt", didn't know what, but the comments "stomp on tisCharsLeftCntxt with a **new this**" & "**global** var"
made sense. It may also solve the inconsistency issue I've with other plugins. This may be off the topic, but still, can you tell the best approach to change parameters in a plugin(p1) from another plugin(p2). A use case is, select options(p1) and search input(p2). When input(P2) is given, it should trigger the clean up / reset of UI for P1. To solve this issue I went with global var,which turned out bad.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I'm not sure I totally understand your followup question, but I will say that for what you're doing here, I would use jQuery UI widgets instead of a jQuery plugin. You call a widget the same way as a plugin, but it provides state and a framework for setting options, dealing with events, and destroying. Think of plugins as stateless--run them for effect and they go away--and widgets as stateful plugins--run them and an instance lives on for interaction and management.